# Masking a UIEffectView with intersecting UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, uiblureffect

I wanted to apply a `UIEffectView` with blur over a tableView but have circular `UIImageView` objects in each cell show through. I used a mask and adapted the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50720221/8289095) to create a method that would iteratively cut out circles above each cell:

```
func cutCircle(inView view: UIView, rect1: CGRect, rect2: CGRect?) {

    // Create new path and mask
    let newMask = CAShapeLayer()

    // Create path to clip
    let newClipPath = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds)

    let path1 = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect1)
    newClipPath.append(path1)

    if let rect2 = rect2 {
        let path2 = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect2)
        //FIXME: Need a way to get a union of both paths!
        //newClipPath.append(path2)
    }

    // If view already has a mask
    if let originalMask = view.layer.mask, let originalShape = originalMask as? CAShapeLayer, let originalPath = originalShape.path {

        // Create bezierpath from original mask's path
        let originalBezierPath = UIBezierPath(cgPath: originalPath)

        // Append view's bounds to "reset" the mask path before we re-apply the original
        newClipPath.append(UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds))

        // Combine new and original paths
        newClipPath.append(originalBezierPath)
    }

    // Apply new mask
    newMask.path = newClipPath.cgPath
    newMask.fillRule = .evenOdd
    view.layer.mask = newMask
}
```

This function is called on the `UIEffectView` for each visible tableview cell using: `for cell in tableView.visibleCells()`. It appends a new circle to the mask.

However, some items have a smaller circle icon overlay, like this:

[image: Icon]

I added the second `CGRect` parameter to the method above to conditionally cut out this circle. However, the mask remains intact where the two circles overlap, like this:

[image: Icon with blur effect]

I looked at a few answers here, as I needed to find a way to get the union of two `UIBezierPath` objects. However, this proved very difficult. I don’t think I can use a drawing context as this is a `UIEffectView` and the mask needs to be cut iteratively.

I tried changing the fill rules (`.evenOdd`, `.nonZero`) but this does not have the desired effect.

Are there any tips for combining two overlapping `UIBezierPath` into a single mask?

---

The overall aim is to achieve this effect with consecutive tableview cells, but some icons will have the extra circle.

[image: Full effect]

Notice how the bottom icon has the extra circle but it is cropped, and my current technique to cut out this extra circle causes the problem noted above, where the overlap is not masked as expected.

Comment: Here is a video showing current state of the effect and demonstrating the problem with the second circle on the bottom icon: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lvjhf6okgr6n3vn/IMG_3903.TRIM.MOV?raw=1

Comment: Couldn't you draw two arcs using addArcWithCenter method and combine them to create a single UIBezierpath?

Comment: @TibinThomas Thanks for this. I had just come across the arc Bézier path method a few minutes ago, and the intersection points of the circles are easy to find. How would I use this method though? Would I need to know the angle of arc of both circles outside the intersection point?

Comment: yes you would need the exact radius of two circles and also the exact start and end angle for both the circle such that the two comined arcs form a single shape you desire.If the circles are of constant sizes it might be easy to calculate.

Comment: @TibinThomas Yes the circles are constant. Larger one is 25pt radius and smaller one is 10pt radius and aligned to the bottom-right of a square bounding the larger circle. Would you be able to submit a demonstration of linking two arcs, as I think this could be what I’m looking for.

Comment: also you could try drawing the bigger one first with addArc and the smaller one connecting the two end points of arc using - addQuadCurveToPoint:controlPoint: method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *addArcWithCenter* method to combine two arcs into desired shape.eg:

```
 #define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees)((M_PI * degrees)/180)

  - (UIBezierPath*)createPath
{
    UIBezierPath* path = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(25, 25) radius:25 startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(30) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(60) clockwise:false];
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(40, 40) radius:10 startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(330) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(120) clockwise:true];
    [path closePath];
    return path;
}
```

I wasn't able to find out the exact points but if you could adjust the constants you could create the perfect shape required.

Comment: Thanks very much. I’ll test it later. Do the points have to be in the context of my imageView’s immediate superview?

Comment: Also, I think I can convert this to Swift quite easily, but are you aware of any differences in Swift with these methods?

Comment: You would be able to convert to swift easily as there are no differences.But I am not sure about the context of points you should use.My assumption is you should use the context of your effectview's frame.

Comment: No problem. Given that I already draw a Bézier curve the same context should work. Thanks

Comment: Please refer @chris answer for the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

try the following code in your function

```
 let newRect: CGRect
 if let rect2 = rect2{
    let raw = rect1.union(rect2)
     let size = max(raw.width, raw.height)
     newRect = CGRect(x: raw.minX, y: raw.minX, width: size, height: size)
    }else{
      newRect = rect1
     }

        let path1 = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: newRect)
        newClipPath.append(path1)
```

Full function

```
func cutCircle(inView view: UIView, rect1: CGRect, rect2: CGRect?) {

        // Create new path and mask
        let newMask = CAShapeLayer()

        // Create path to clip
        let newClipPath = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds)

        let newRect: CGRect
        if let rect2 = rect2{
            let raw = rect1.union(rect2)
            let size = max(raw.width, raw.height) // getting the larger value in order to draw a proper circle
            newRect = CGRect(x: raw.minX, y: raw.minX, width: size, height: size)
        }else{
            newRect = rect1
        }

        let path1 = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: newRect)
        newClipPath.append(path1)



        // If view already has a mask
        if let originalMask = view.layer.mask, let originalShape = originalMask as? CAShapeLayer, let originalPath = originalShape.path {

            // Create bezierpath from original mask's path
            let originalBezierPath = UIBezierPath(cgPath: originalPath)

            // Append view's bounds to "reset" the mask path before we re-apply the original
            newClipPath.append(UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds))

            // Combine new and original paths
            newClipPath.append(originalBezierPath)
        }

        // Apply new mask
        newMask.path = newClipPath.cgPath
        newMask.fillRule = .evenOdd
        view.layer.mask = newMask
    }
```

I used the built-in function [union](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1455837-union) to create a raw CGRect and then I get the max value to draw a proper circle.

Comment: Thanks for this - I’ll try it out later

Comment: This will draw a single circle around both the circular icons (i.e. a circle within the square that bounds both of them). At present, my smaller optional icon is always contained within the 'square' of the larger one anyway, aligned to the bottom-right.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the accepted answer (from user [Tibin Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8181347/tibin-thomas)) I was able to adapt the use of arcs with `UIBezierPath` to obtain exactly what I needed. I have accepted his answer but posted my final code here for future reference.

Of note, before calling this method, I have to convert the `CGRect` coordinates from the `UIImageView`s superview to the coordinate space of my `UIEffectView`. I also apply an inset of -1 to obtain the 1pt border. Thus the radii used are 1 greater than the radii of my `UIImageView`s.

[image: Masked icons]

```
func cutCircle(inView view: UIView, rect1: CGRect, rect2: CGRect?) {

    // Create new path and mask
    let newMask = CAShapeLayer()

    // Create path to clip
    let newClipPath = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds)

    // Center of rect1
    let x1 = rect1.midX
    let y1 = rect1.midY
    let center1 = CGPoint(x: x1, y: y1)

    // New path
    let newPath: UIBezierPath

    if let rect2 = rect2 {
        // Need to get two arcs - main icon and padlock icon
        // Center of rect2
        let x2 = rect2.midX
        let y2 = rect2.midY
        let center2 = CGPoint(x: x2, y: y2)
        // These values are hard-coded for 25pt radius main icon and bottom-right-aligned 10pt radius padlock icon with a 1pt additional border
        newPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center1, radius: 26, startAngle: 1.2, endAngle: 0.3, clockwise: true)
        newPath.addArc(withCenter: center2, radius: 11, startAngle: 5.8, endAngle: 2.2, clockwise: true)
    } else {
        // Only single circle is needed
        newPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect1)
    }

    newPath.close()

    newClipPath.append(newPath)

    // If view already has a mask
    if let originalMask = view.layer.mask,
        let originalShape = originalMask as? CAShapeLayer,
        let originalPath = originalShape.path {

        // Create bezierpath from original mask's path
        let originalBezierPath = UIBezierPath(cgPath: originalPath)

        // Append view's bounds to "reset" the mask path before we re-apply the original
        newClipPath.append(UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds))

        // Combine new and original paths
        newClipPath.append(originalBezierPath)
    }

    // Apply new mask
    newMask.path = newClipPath.cgPath
    newMask.fillRule = .evenOdd
    view.layer.mask = newMask
}
```

Comment: Great work!You should share the credits as I provided only a suggestion and u perfected it.!

Comment: @TibinThomas Thanks, but I wouldn't have got there without your answer, and I can't give myself the bounty :)